# how to Dynamically select which method to execute?

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, reflection

I want to dynamically select the Method 
I've one method of 20 overload and i want to dynamically select the methods
Suppose I have Generic `List<MyClass> lst  = new List<MyClass>();`

```
class Myclass
{
    String Paraname  {Get; Set;}
    String KeyName {Get; Set;}
    String Border {Get; Set;}
    .... So on
}

lst.add(new Myclass(Paraname="SomePara", KeyName="SomeKey"));
lst.add(new Myclass(Paraname="SomePara", KeyName="SomeKey"));
lst.add(new Myclass(Paraname="SomePara", KeyName="SomeKey", Border="Left"));
```

Now i want to dynamically call the method on the basis of parameters added in the list.
Thanks.

Comment: How will you decide which method to call?

Comment: Your question isn't too clear--could you explain a bit more what you're trying to accomplish?  And which methods are you talking about?

Comment: Please describe more detail info. not sure what you want to do. generally use refection you can dynamically select method to execute.

Comment: Suppose i have 25 overload for AddCell() <br/>and parameter list is defined in Generic List build on conditions specified <br/> now when looping the list methods to be dynamically select.

Answer (score 1):

Ultimately you need to just look at your list and each item and have some criteria to decide which method to call.  Once you decide that you can invoke the method as such

```
Type myType = Type.GetType("MyClass");
        ConstructorInfo myConstructor = myType.GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes);
        object myClassObject = myConstructor.Invoke(new object[]{});


        MethodInfo myMethod = myType.GetMethod("Method Name");
        object myValue = myMethod.Invoke(myClassObject, new object[]{100});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make use of this:

```
MethodInfo.Invoke(...)
```

And here is how: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a89hcwhh.aspx

Answer (score -1):

You should better read some articles about OOP and try to build a more friendly architecture f your app. Then all your questions will be more understandable - and differ from current.

Comment: Try to understand the question first

Comment: You should add more details for your question, otherwise it seems like you want different behaviour for your class based on it state - it's definetely bad architecture with your current design.